# How do I model a decreasing Spiral in blender?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I am trying to model a fancy shower stall in blender 3.0.  -- I want it to look like this

[image: section of a floor plan showing fancy spiral shower stall]

I currently had modeled it by tracing it with adding verts -- then extruding on the z axis and adding a solidifier modifier, its "ok" not great — too rough — How would I model this so it is properly smooth and even?

Thanks
TIM

Comment: please provide your blend file and your result screenshot.  I would say your way is right, maybe you just didn't use enough vertices? I would create the spiral by this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxBco.jpg (it's in the delivered curve-add-on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes it helps to do some research.  Spiral showers aren't really based on a spiral, usually.  Here's a typical plan for one:

[image: Spiral shower plan drawing]

As you can see, the "spiral" is really composed of two half circles; with a 3rd half circle thrown in for good measure.  So, you could enable the add-on to draw spirals and fiddle with the settings until you got one that gave what you wanted, *or* you could model it as two half circles:

[image: Modeled "spiral"]

The trick here is that the lower half circle's radius is 1/2 that of the upper half circle, and it has been moved exactly that distance to the right.

When the two half circles are overlapped, select all of the vertices and type <kbd>M</kbd> and select *by distance*  to merge the two vertices that overlap.

Extrude the resulting curve in the Z distance to the height of the wall.

Add a solidify modifier, and set the width to the wall thickness.

You can extrude the far left vertex to create the side wall, but if you do, do that before you extrude and solidify.  Set it to smooth shading and enable *Auto Smooth* and the result might look something like this:

[image: Spiral shower]

You can set *smooth shading* by right clicking on the wall in object mode and selecting *Shade Smooth*.  This will look bad until you enable *Auto Smooth* by going to the *properties editor* → *Object Data Properties* tab → *Normals* panel and clicking the little box:

[image: Enabling Auto Smooth]

You can add the *Solidify* modifier by going to the *Properties Editor* → *Modifiers Panel*; clicking the *Add Modifiers* box and selecting *Solidify*:

[image: Add Modifiers menu showing the solidify modifier]

Enter the wall thickness you want in the *Thickness* input of the solidify modifier. I used .1m for a nice thick wall:

[image: Solidify modifier showing the Thickness input]

Comment: Thanks - -that works good !!!

Comment: You're welcome.